# Como trazer o arquivo javascript para o tema wordpress via codigo

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Eu tenho dois arquivos javascript dentro de uma pasta chamada (js) e quero saber como chamar ele no código do tema que estou criando. Mas como fazer isso, eu sei que tenho que utilizar o functions.php ou estou errado? peço que me ajudem pois sou novo na criação de temas wordpress e estou como muita dificuldade de resolver isso.

com o css eu fiz isso e funcionou

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/style.css" media="screen,projection"/>
```

Comment: Já buscou na documentação? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta já resolvi o problema, coloquei uma function que registra no login os scripts carregados no footer. Obrigado

Comment: Se resolveu o problema, poste a solução como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu utilizo assim.

**Para javascript:**

```
wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/assets/js/scripts.js',array('jquery'));
```

**Para style:**

```
wp_enqueue_style('responsive', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/assets/css/responsivo.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
```